# List with words and float, count sum of float

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sum

I have a list:

```
a = ["apple", 1.20, "orange", 1.30]
```

I want to get the sum of floats. Using Python 3

I tried:

```
floating = []

for i in a:
    if i.isdigit():
        floating.append(i)
```

But float has no attribut isdigit.

So I tried:

```
float_str = []
float_float = []

float_str.append(a[::-2])

for i in float_str:
    float_float.append(float(i))
```

So here I get a list in list with floats, and then i just get... lost.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I was checking if i in a isdigit but it does not work. And I was also trying to get everysecond item in list to a new list and sum it, but... I'm lost in sintax

Comment: You should add your current approach to your question, and detail what exactly is wrong with it and why you don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first determine the [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) of the element in the list.
And then append them to the list `floating`. The [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function of python3 returns the class to which the element belongs to.

```
for i in a:
    if type(i) is float:
        floating.append(i)
```

And this is what I got as output,

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i in a:
...    if type(i) is float:
...      l.append(i)
... 
>>> print(l)
[1.2, 1.3]
```